# poor font quality when exporting to pdf

Tags: fonts, pdftex, lyx

I use LyX 2.0 and export with pdflatex.

When writing standard text and exporting to pdf, the font gets rigid. Text written in math mode, though, is exported crystal clear. I've tested that on several computers - but they all show the same problem.

I can't get it, since it's the same font in both cases. Even when choosing italics for standard text, which is how math mode text is showed, I get the same result.

I attached the screenshot below , if for some reason the difference will not show on the pdf itself. (obviously that compromises the quality, but the difference can still be seen clearly).

[image]

Comment: It is not the same font. Math and text use different fonts. Screenshots are not very useful, the log-file or the pdf would show the fonts used. But my guess is you should install the cm-super fonts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears that the problem is that your LyX and LaTeX installation is using bitmap fonts instead of vector fonts for text. Try setting the default roman font for the document to Latin Modern Roman in the document settings.

`Document > Settings > Fonts > Roman > Latin Modern Roman`

Comment: Changing the font is probably not very useful since the user is probably missing most of the standard vector fonts from his distribution. Making sure that the vector fonts are actually installed would be the first step.

Comment: I suppose that is a possibility. However, in LyX's font selection menu fonts that are not installed have a "(not installed)" appended after the name of the font in the menu. As soon as the OP (or whoever) tries to change the font to Latin Modern Roman they will find out whether or not the font is installed.

Comment: @JohnReed thanks! changed the default roman font as you said and it solved my problem. looks like some kind of magic...

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem, too; when I removed this:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

the problem disappears and the fonts become very nice and sharp again!

Maybe you are using `fontenc`, or maybe it's some other package that's causing the problem. Check this possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Today I have started to use LaTeX and I noticed that the characters on .pdf file was not clear like in your case. And I was searching on the internet, I've found this code:

```
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
```

I don't know how it works but it worked!

You can check here for details -> [High quality PDF output from LaTeX and TeX](http://dsanta.users.ch/resources/type1.html)!

Comment: Those packages are very very obsolete and outdated. You shouldn't  need them anymore.

Comment: Either install package `cm-super` that provides Computer Modern fonts in font encoding `T1` as vector fonts (Type 1). Or use Latin Modern fonts (more glyphs, better quality) via `\usepackage{lmodern}`. These fonts are kind of successor for the Computer Modern fonts. They work with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and also provide OpenType versions for LuaTeX and XeTeX.